# Dividing each slice of a MATLAB 3D array by a different number

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D MATLAB function.

I want to multiply each slice of the matrix by a different number.

I tried to implement this by bsxfun in the following example code:

```
 a=randi(10,4,3,2);
 b=[2 3];
 c=bsxfun(@times,a,b)
```

I intended that the first 4*3 slice of 'a' would be multiplied by 2, and the second 4*3 slice of 'a' would be multiplied by 3.

However, I only got the following error:

??? Error using ==> bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two
input arrays must match each other.

How to solve the problem without using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you need to make the dimensions of the vector and the matrix match. Since `b` is a row vector, you can make the slices of the matrix into columns. You can do this with [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
a = randi(10, 4, 3, 2);
b = [2 3];
ap = permute(a, [1 3 2]);
c = bsxfun(@times, ap, b)
```

Then, to get the result matrix back into the correct shape, you need to permute again. You can either figure out the correct permutation order (it happens to be the same in this case, i.e. `[1 3 2]`) or you can use [ipermute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ipermute.html) (inverse permute) and let it figure it out for you. Just give it the same permutation order you gave `permute` earlier.

```
c = ipermute(c, [1 3 2]);
```

Alternatively, you can permute the vector `b` to be the right shape to multiply the slices by making it extend in the 3rd dimension:

```
a = randi(10, 4, 3, 2);
b = [2 3];
bp = permute(b, [1 3 2]);
c = bsxfun(@times, a, bp)
```

In this case, since we didn't change `a`, we don't have to permute `c` again to get the correct shape.